# Build Hadoop Native Library(2.5.1) on Raspberry PI

Tags: maven, hadoop

I am encountering the native library problem on Raspberry PI. So, I am trying to recompile the native library. But this error has been haunting me for days. If anyone has any suggestions or ways to troubleshoot I would really appreciate the help.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7 run(make) on project hadoop-common: An Ant Build Exception has occurred: exec turned:1
around Ant part ...<exec dir=/home.hduser/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-common-prject/hadoop-common/target/native" executable="cmake" failonerror="true"> ... @4:133 in /home/hduser/hadoop-2.5.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

And tried different methods such as:

1. chown -R on the source folder
2. making sure I have libssl-dev and zlib1g-dev and cmake installed
3. compile would work without native lib
4. tried -e -X with the package option but i cannot find much from the error info.